# Dart is not running in vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, sdk, vscode-extensions

I decided to start coding a language and I chose dart i previousy coded Html,css and javascript as my first language. I have no experience with flutter or vs code so when I downloaded the dart extension and sdk. I tried to run code it is recognized as dart because of its color but isnt running. Here is an open python document and Dart document.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X0kt.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2QpT.png)

I restarted Vs code multiple times but It didnt work. This is really frustrating cause I havent started coding and I have already ran into a ditch

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to choise os, then follow the instructions:
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install

Comment: This is not just flutter even kotlin no language is running on my vs code except python please help me anime kid bro

Comment: No language on vs code is working except python.Please help me russian american kid bro

Comment: follow the instructions